# Get root folder of extracted Zipfile

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-zipfile

Using Zipfile in Python 3.6, I am able to successfully extract a zip using:

```
with zipfile.ZipFile(my_zip,"r") as zip_ref:
    zip_ref.extractall('./download')
```

[image]

The zip will always contain one top level folder:

- with a unique ID filename that is different to the original ZIP filename
- Ends with .gdb
- Has other folders and files within it.

I need to return the name of the top level extracted folder, highlighted above.

*zip_ref.namelist()* and *zip_ref.filelist* = Returns all the files under the root folder that was extracted.

I can see a way of doing this using replace on one of the paths of the files in the underlying folder, but feels like the wrong approach.

Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 1):

I'd use [`zipfile.Path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.Path) for this. Use is similar to `pathlib.Path`.

Unlike zip files, these path objects can represent directories. If you're confident there is exactly one top level directory that should be created by `extractall`, you could do this:

```
with zipfile.ZipFile(my_zip,"r") as zip_ref:
     relativepath, = zipfile.Path(zip_ref).iterdir()
     print(relativepath.name)  # Should print the name of the folder, without prefix or slashes.
     # If you want the location on the filesystem it can be found, don't forget to join it to the directory, like with pathlib.Path('./download') / relativepath.name
    zip_ref.extractall('./download')
```